# PrimeNG v10.0.0, p-table footer disappears when [responsive]='true' and grid is responsive

Tags: css, angular, datatables, primeng

I am building a weeks expense report component. The report should be responsive, so I have the detail in the body with column totals in the footer.

I am using PrimeNG library in an Angular 10 application.  This is a PrimeNG CSS question.  The expense report normally displays header, body and footer.  When the expense report is responsive it only displays the body.  This appears to be by Primefaces design per the following **table.css** file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-thead > tr > th,
  .p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td {
    display: none !important;
  }
  ...
```

I am trying to get the footer to display, but I have been unsuccessful.  When I look in Chrome developer tools I see the above **table.css** has overridden my CSS in the following application **style.css** file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    border: 0 none;
  }
  .p-datatable.p-datatable-responsive .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td .p-column-title {
    padding: .4rem;
    min-width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

I basically took the above CSS from the **table.css** and changed it to be tfoot instead of tbody.  I see the above CSS in Chrome developer tools below the CSS in **table.css**, but the *display: block;* line has a strike-through.

My CSS is setup in the *angular.json* file as follows:

```
angular.json
  "build": {
    ...,
      "styles": [
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
        "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css",
        "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
        "src/styles.css"
      ],
```

The following is a sample component to demonstrate the problem.

```
<p-table id='weekTotals-grid' [value]='items'  dataKey='ExpenseTypeId' [responsive]='true'>
  <ng-template pTemplate='header'>
    <tr>
      <th style='width: 170px;'></th>
      <th><div style='width: 100px;'>Total</div></th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate='body' let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class='p-column-title'>Expense Type</span>
        {{ rowData['ExpenseType'] }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class='p-column-title'>Total</span>
        <div style='width: 80px;' class='nsg-wet-numeric'>
          {{ rowData['ExpenseTotal'] }}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate='footer' style='border-top: 1px solid black;'>
    <tr>
      <td>Totals</td>
      <td>
        <span class='p-column-title'>Grand Total</span>
          {{ grandTotal }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

The typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  items: any[];
  grandTotal: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {ExpenseTypeId: 1, ExpenseType: 'Gas', ExpenseTotal: 20.0},
      {ExpenseTypeId: 2, ExpenseType: 'Food', ExpenseTotal: 12.88},
      {ExpenseTypeId: 3, ExpenseType: 'Mileage', ExpenseTotal: 5.50}
      ];
    this.grandTotal = 38.38;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried root: ng-deep::, but I could not get that to work.  So, I went with how the StackBlitz example works and not use [responsive]='true', but use a class as follows:

```
/* Responsive styleClass='p-datatable-responsive-footer' */
.p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td .p-column-title,
.p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td .p-column-title {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td,
    .p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td {
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        border: 0 none;
    }
    .p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td .p-column-title,
    .p-datatable-responsive-footer .p-datatable-tfoot > tr > td .p-column-title {
        padding: .4rem;
        min-width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

I placed the above in the application **style.css** file. I think this solution with some changes could be used for any HTML table.  Make sure you use an uppercase C (styleClass).

```
<p-table id='weekTotals-grid' [value]='items' dataKey='ExpenseTypeId' styleClass='p-datatable-responsive-footer'>
  ...
</p-table>
```